# Can I load a 3rd Party Plugin/Extension in CefSharp?

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am trying to load an existing 3rd party plugin to CefSharp (WinForms).

Am I supposed to achieve this via the RequestContext.LoadExtension method?

I have tried the following

***BrowserForm.cs***

```
public BrowserForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    IRequestContext cont = new RequestContext(new CustomerRequestContextHandler());
    cont.LoadExtension(@"C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\digojkgonhgmnohbapdfjllpnmjmdhpg\1.5.5_0", null, new ExtensionHandler());

    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("",cont);
    toolStripContainer.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(browser);

    displayPlugins();
}
```

**ExtensionHandler.cs**

```
public void OnExtensionLoaded(IExtension extension)
{

}
```

This method fires suggesting that it is able to find and load the extension at that location.

But a subequent call to :-

```
List<WebPluginInfo> plugins = await Cef.GetPlugins();
```

Does not retrieve this plugin.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: GetPlugins has absolutely nothing to do with loading an extension. The project source contains a simple example,  search on GitHub for LoadExtension. CEF only supports a subset of the Chromium extension public API, it may not be possible to load your extension.

Comment: Ah ok - understood.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes - a quick scan of the 3rd party code revealed it was using a whole load of API that CEF does not yet support.

Comment: CEF can support them now in the Chrome runtime. It should be eventually available in CefSharp: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4123

We at DotNetBrowser has released a preview of our extensions support, you can check it out. https://dev.to/dotnetbrowser/chrome-extensions-in-net-web-view-controls-11lm